# List organization on individual profile signup

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a join form for visitors on our site, and I'd like to give them the option of adding what school they go to.

I've imported schools as organizations, and I think I know how to link individual contacts to "Student of.." the school when I import our list, but going forward how do individuals link themselves to particular schools when they sign up?

I'd like for them to be able to type in the name of the school and be presented with suggestions (to try and avoid creating duplicates with spelling differences).

Any idea how to do it?  Thanks!

I've got CiviCRM 4.7.25 and am using Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Contact Reference field (one of the types of Custom Fields that you can create) and then display that in your profile and limit that to just the group of schools. users need to have permissions to use the autocomplete option so you need to visit /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Faccess%2Fwp-permissions&reset=1 and find th permission "CiviCRM: access contact reference fields 
Allow entering data into contact reference fields" and give it to your anonymous visitors. (You may also need to give "CiviCRM: access AJAX API 
Allow API access even if Access CiviCRM is not granted")

The above won't do this as a Relationships, which is the ideal, but I don't know how that is done via Profiles for WP

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new at all this.  

What is a contact reference field?  And what kind of permission would they need?  How would I grant it?  Would they be able to add new schools as well, or just pick from a list?

Comment: Explained the field in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

We do exactly this for a Greenschools Canada project; Students select their School from a list (group) of registered Greenschools. They add their name, data they have collected and a relationship is automatically added.

It’s on Drupal w/ Webform CiviCRM - out of the box.

Keep Wordpress for other bits of your website but if you expect to be doing a lot of interactive data management consider moving your CiviCRM to a Drupal subdomain so that you can leverage many already existing tools out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with petednz, ideally you should do this with a relationship between the school and the individual contact. But I have no idea how to accomplish this with Wordpress without development.

I know about the Contact 7 CiviCRM integration, but that would mean you would have to develop a CiviCRM extensions that picks up your submitted data and process that into CiviCRM. If you are interested, the extension can be found here: https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-civicrm-integration/

Comment: I looked at the link you sent, but I couldn't make sense of what it is or how it would address my issue.  Sorry, I'm really new at CiviCRM, I'm not a developer.

Comment: If you are not a developer, then I think this would be a little too much :-) I would ignore the link then, as stated it means you would have to develop an extension or have someone develop it for you.